# Deploying an Azure Function to AKS deploys to my local instead of AKS

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-functions

I'm trying to deploy an Azure Function to my AKS cluster using the following command:

```
func kubernetes deploy --name orchestrator --registry <ACR name> --namespace orchestrator
```

Now this builds the image, but then instead of pushing to my ACR and deploying to AKS it builds the image and runs it in my Docker Desktop. I've tried turning Docker Desktop off, but then the func command doesn't work.

I've followed this documentation from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-kubernetes-keda

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

EDIT:
The build is being created, but the next command "docker push..." isn't starting for some reason.

I checked to container logs and it seems my function has startup issues due to a missing connection string. I did add this connection string in the local.settings.json, so I don't really know what's up there.

Comment: HAve you verified that your current context points to your AKS cluster?

Comment: Yes, running kubectl get nodes outputs the node in my AKS cluster.

Comment: Make sure you aks cluster is created, acr is there and that you have logged into your acr before running that command
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#deploying-a-function-to-aks-using-acr

Comment: I checked all three suggestions. I logged out of my Docker Hub and local docker account, and logged in using both the az cli and docker command to my acr.